# Detecting and validating Mime Types in ZF2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, mime-types

I'm trying to restrict certain file types from being uploaded in zend framework 2 (only want to allow .png and .jpg files), but I am running into some issues with doing this.

It uploads even though I only specify the two mime types in the validators. Here is the code

```
  $file = new File();
        $form->setInputFilter($file->getInputFilter());

        $captions = $request->getPost()->toArray();
        $get_file = $this->params()->fromFiles('file');


        $data = array_merge_recursive($this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(), $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray());

        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $size = new Size(array('max' => FileHandler::FILESIZE));
            $mime = new MimeType('image/jpg,image/png');

            $adapter = (new Http())->setValidators(array($size, $mime), $get_file);

            if (!$adapter->isValid()) {
                $error_msg = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();

                foreach ($error_msg as $key => $value) {
                    $error[] = $value;
                }

                $form->setMessages(array('file' => $error));

                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/admin/upload-failure');
```

As you can see, it is set as a validator to check for the size and mime type.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating the `MimeType` validator wrong by passing an invalid option format. It should be an array with 'mimeType' key. Check the available options [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/File/MimeType.php#L80-L85).

Instead of trying to validate your files using an Http instance inline, i recommend writing a custom dedicated InputFilter class for this job. Zend Framework 2 has a special [Zend\InputFilter\FileInput](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/FileInput.php) which differs from others especially about validation flow: validators of the FileInput are runs before the filters. It also automatically injects and uses the [Zend\Validator\File\Upload](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/File/Upload.php) validator which also checks files against possible errors occur during uploading.

You can easily utilize all of this built-in features by creating a custom `MyFileFilter` class like below:

```
<?php
namespace Application\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\FileInput;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator\File\Size;
use Zend\Validator\File\MimeType;

class MyFileFilter extends InputFilter
{    
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct($postFile)
    {
        $size = new Size(['max' => FileHandler::FILESIZE]);
        $mime = new MimeType(['mimeType' => 'image/jpg,image/png']);

        $input = new FileInput('file');
        $input->setValue($postFile);
        $input->getValidatorChain()
              ->attach($size)
              ->attach($mime);

        $this->add($input);
    }
}
```

So, in your controllers or services, you can do this:

```
$filter = new \Application\InputFilter\MyFileFilter($get_file);

if($filter->isValid()) {
    // ...
}
```

Other good thing about this approach is you can re-use this MyInputFilter for other upload requirements in your application just making some minor improvements. (Parameterizing the mime types and size values etc..)